# Remove MapServer comments in GetCapabilities request

Tags: mapserver, getcapabilities

MapServer adds a XML-comment right before the `<Service>` tag in a `GetCapabilities` repsonse like this:

```
<!-- MapServer version 7.4.2 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG [...] -->
```

Is it possible to remove this comment somehow?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible without rewriting XML with some external utility. Write mail to MapServer-users list and ask if you do not get any better answer from here.

Comment: It appears in the SOS and WMS outputs but not WFS or WCS

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that this is a WMS GetCapabilities response. Didn't test it with WFS yet.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible using out of the box MapServer.  However, you can use [MapScript](https://mapserver.org/mapscript/) (MapServer's scripting capabilitiy) to intercept the response and remove the comment as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is nevertheless disappointing as this should be configurable. The MapServer comment is not useful in any way in a production environment and only adds unwanted data and traffic.

Comment: @baal I find it useful, both to know what service versions we're running, and also to know what versions others are using as part of a help desk function I involved in

Comment: Echoing @nmtoken for debugging usefulness.  Having said this, feel free to open an issue or bring this up on the MapServer users mailing list.